# How to change pycharm python docstring color

Tags: pycharm

I stuck a long time with setting pycharm code editor background color, seems pycharm has an overcomplete color settings, but very elusive, and no good documentation, I tried to change the docstring color to green, but after apply and save, nothing happened:
[image]

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting pycharm solve the problem...